# Bestiary catching system

Tags: path-of-exile

With the new Bestiary update I am trying to play around catching with nets I've gotten from drops. I noticed that when a Beast rages it breaks the net and is immune to netting until it cools down.

I'd like to know more about this rage system:

1. Is there any signs/condition for it to rage? So far I've managed multiple catches without the monster raging but also failed a few because it did and died to my dps during the rage period.
2. How do I know when the rage ends other than spamming 'v' until the next net is thrown?
3. Is there any other effects to rage? So far I noticed the Beast will regain some health but are there any other effects?

Comment: Typically enraged monsters have a reddish swirl sort of pattern over them. Good examples are Argus when enraged or the Canyon map Bosses; when you kill one the other will enrage. [Normal argus](https://d1u5p3l4wpay3k.cloudfront.net/pathofexile_gamepedia/2/26/Argus.png?version=ff1a2bdeef482353afa3f8e2ed0839d2) vs [enraged](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XJavstC-JP4/maxresdefault.jpg). Idk for sure if bestiary monsters have this effect as well, they are usually surrounded by too many other mobs to see them or this effect well.

Answer (score 1):

1) If the hp of the monster is not low enough 3 seconds after throwing the net it will rage and escape, this threshhold depends on the type of net en monster. I don't know the threshhold. But making it run out of hp while netted will guarantee a catch.

2) I think there is a visual cue, but I'm not sure, I'll check tonight and update the answer.

3) As far as I know the only effect of raging is that it is impossible to catch for a few seconds. And it heals up some part of it's hp.